# C++11: Avoid downcasting when setting member variables for derived class

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, class-design, downcast

Let's say I want to build a `Car` which has components like `Motor`, `Tire`, etc. which are all derived from a "component" base class. Each component has its own states (i.e. motor has RPM, tire has pressure, and so on) as a subclass. A `Car` class stores all component classes.

Now I want the `Car` class to have a "save car states" function which returns an object that loops over a vector of all components and holds all states of all components to restore them later. Each component should individually be responsible of storing and restoring its states to the car state object.

The code below is a minimal example of what I came up with. However it has (at least) two ugly parts in the code, which I think should be avoided:

- First, I need to downcast a Base class of states, when I want to set the car components back to a previously saved state. Is this a valid case to downcast? I read that this is usually a sign of bad design. Thus, how can I improve this? Did I completely misuse the concept of polymorphism?
- Second, I need to get the raw pointer of an unique_ptr to pass the state back to the component and read it there. Seems pretty ugly to me as well.
  Thanks for your comments!

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class StateClass{
};

class component{
public:
  virtual std::unique_ptr<StateClass> saveStates() = 0;
  virtual void loadStates(StateClass* states) = 0;
};

class Motor:public component
{
public:
  Motor(){
    mstates.rpm = 6000;
    mstates.motorstates::oilLevel = 1.0;
  }
  struct motorstates: public StateClass{
    double rpm;
    double oilLevel;
    void setStates(){
    }
  };

  std::unique_ptr<StateClass> saveStates(){
    std::unique_ptr<StateClass> tmp(new motorstates(mstates));
    return tmp;
  };

  void loadStates(StateClass* states){
    motorstates* savedState = static_cast<motorstates*>(states); // <=== should this be avoided??
    mstates.rpm = savedState->rpm;
    mstates.oilLevel = savedState->oilLevel;
  };

// private:
  void someMethod1();
  void someMethod2();
  motorstates mstates;
};

class Car{
public:
  Car(){
    listOfComponents.push_back(&amotor);
  }
  std::vector<component*> listOfComponents;

// private:
  Motor amotor;

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StateClass>> saveState(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StateClass> > states;
    for(auto comp : listOfComponents){
      states.push_back(comp->saveStates());
    }
    return states;
  }

  void loadState(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StateClass>>& savedStates){
    int cntstates = 0;
    for(auto comp: listOfComponents){
      comp->loadStates(savedStates.at(cntstates++).get());  // <=== this seems pretty ugly
    };
  }
};

int main()
{
  Car acar;

  std::cout << "Car rpm: " << acar.amotor.mstates.rpm << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Saving states..." << std::endl;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<StateClass>> savedState = acar.saveState();

  std::cout << "Changing car rpm..." << std::endl;
  acar.amotor.mstates.rpm = 5000;
  std::cout << "Current car rpm: " << acar.amotor.mstates.rpm << std::endl;

  StateClass* tmpState = savedState.at(0).get();
  Motor::motorstates* tmpMotorstates = static_cast<Motor::motorstates*>(tmpState);
  std::cout << "Saved rpm: " << tmpMotorstates->rpm << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Loading state... " << std::endl;
  acar.loadState(savedState);
  std::cout << "Current car rpm: " << acar.amotor.mstates.rpm << std::endl;

}
```

Additional remarks (see comments):

- I read about visitor classes, but they seem to complicate things more than they would help to write readable code.
- I actually only need to save states during runtime, not to a file
- The car was just an example. My real project uses lots of component classes with hundreds of states. Also some states are supposed to be restored, others not.

Comment: What kind of storing and restoring do you need to do? Is this a serialization problem, where you are saving the C++ class to a binary or XML file?

Comment: Visitors are the traditional way to go.  They certainly solve the problems you observe w.r.t. ugliness and are _specifically designed_ to solve the problem with downcasting.  So your only issue with them is "complicate things more than they" should?  That might turn out to be a matter of taste.  Check out this article [Defining Visitors Inline in Modern C++](https://accu.org/index.php/articles/2021) and its references too to see if you can find something more to your liking.

Comment: I don't think storing derived classes into a `unique_ptr` is save, if the base class does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at inline visitor and try to implement it.

Comment: @jwimberly I looked and serialization, especially the cereal library, but I actually only need to save states during runtime, not to a file.

Comment: @chtz uh, i didn't know that, thanks formte it, ill implement that

Comment: From your simple example I still don't see the point of using this complicated state loading/storing mechanism anyway. Why can't you just copy the entire car?

Comment: The car was just an example. My real project uses lots of component classes with hundreds of states. Also some states are supposed to be restored, others not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Design issue

These ugly things are symptoms of a design issue caused by the mutual dependency between the `Component` structure and the `State` structure.

In other words, you have defined a polymorphic `State`, but most of the time you use it expecting a specific state subclass.

In addition, the configuration of the car is in fact also a state:  if you would change anything in its configuration, you'd no longer be able to restore anything (even if you just added an irrelevant spare-part).

#### Make your code more robust

If you keep this design, you should in any case make the code more robust.  What happens, for example, if by accident you give a State pointer which does not meet the expectations ?

```
motorstates* savedState = static_cast<motorstates*>(states);
```

This would be UB ! Fortunately your state is already a polymorphic type.  So you could use dynamic cast instead:

```
motorstates* savedState = dynamic_cast<motorstates*>(states);  
if (savedState==nullptr) {  // this is true if the state was not of correct class
    //ouch !  At least you'd know
}
```

*(By the way, as a rule of thumb that can prevent problems: if you've got a virtual member function, better give your class a virtual destructor.)*

#### Alternative design 1:  the memento

A good option for a save/restore capability is to use a [memento design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html).  The idea is that the the obect saves or restores its state from a memento, which content and structure is unknown from the "caretaker" (i.e. the code responsible of keeping the memnto and invoke the safekeeping).

Consequence:  the internals of a `CarMemento` would be known to the Car only.  This leans that you'll not be able to restore a partial state (e.g. engine state only).  The mementos would not necessarily be polymorphic objects : the save state/restore state would anyway use specific Memento types for the different Components.

It seems that you have the components as private members and not as a dynamic item.  If this is confirmed this would be the safest way to do.

#### Alternative design 2: composite

Another approach would be adopt the [composite design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) for your component and combine it with the memento.

I'd then implement the state-saving using the principle of serialisation (even if it's into a memory object), and saveguard not only the states but the full composite structure. I'd then use a factory to deserialize a saved state.

However, if you prefer to save only the states of the object, you could combine composite with memento:

- either giving the memnto's internals a composite structure, assuming that it replicates always the component that was saved.
- or use some unique identifies to identify the components in the car, and construct the memento as a map container, which returns a state for  an identifier. This approach would have advantage that it's flexible in case you add or remove coponents from your care between the saving and teh restoring of the state.

In both case however, you'd have to use dynamic cast to ensure that the types of the saved state match with the type of the state to be restored.